# Concurrent Modification Exception Despite HashMap Being Restored To Original State?

Tags: java, exception

I am currently working on a project for a Software Engineering type class and running into what I see as a strange error. According to the research/debugging that I've done Java's *ConcurrentModificationException* is typically thrown when a HashMap is modified by the time that its *next()* method is called.

To give you an idea of problem domain this is a chess game where I am determining checkmate. Currently my code is structured as follows:

1. Get all keys of HashMap (board)
2. *for(Coordinate key: keys)* ...
3. Move *Piece* to spot on board
4. Check if King is under attack
5. Move piece back
6. Loop

This section of code generates a *ConcurrentModificationException* upon looping, despite the fact that the HashMap is in the same state as it was when the iteration began - size and exact values.

Any ideas what might cause this?

Loop:

```
for(ValidatorCoordinate key: keys){
    if(board.findPiece(key).getPieceType() != XiangqiPieceType.GENERAL 
        && moveValid(key, spaceBetween, color)
        && tryBlock(key, spaceBetween, dst, color)){
                return true;
    }
}
```

tryBlock() (Method where HashMap is Modified)

```
private boolean tryBlock(ValidatorCoordinate source, 
    ValidatorCoordinate destination,
    ValidatorCoordinate underAttack, XiangqiColor c){

        board.movePiece(source, destination, c);
        boolean blocked = !underAttack(underAttack, c);
        board.movePiece(destination, source, c);
        return blocked;
}
```

The *movePiece()* method definitely moves pieces within the HashMap (thoroughly tested at this point)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit: For clarification, this general approach worked until I abstracted away the movement to another method (*tryBlock*). Previously the contents of *tryBlock* were inside of the loop, and no exception was thrown. This is also why I'm concerned about this, as to me it should have thrown the exception there as well.

Comment: Any modification is rejected by `HashMap`, even if it ends up coming back to the original state.  (For good reason; even if the contents of the map are the same, the internal arrangement of the hash buckets can differ.)

Comment: Just to clarify, is there any reason why this Exception would not be thrown until looping then? The modification is technically allowed, but the loop complains.

Additionally, this same approach worked previously, however the moving of the piece was not abstracted away into another method at that point. This error has only come up in refactoring.

Thanks!

Comment: The `Iterator` methods are generally the ones that throw the ConcurrentModificationException.  The modification methods don't know there's an iteration still going on.

Comment: But even if what Louis says aboit rearranging buckets weren't the case, it would be necessary to keep some representation of the map in order to know that the state has been restored. And how many steps should be detectable as restoring the state - 1 (insert, delete)? 2 (insert, insert, delete, delete)? 3... It's easier just to say "no modifications at all" than to have to keep an arbitrary amount of additional state to use on the off-chance you might attempt to restore it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered switching from HashMap to ConcurrentHashMap?  The latter allows for parallel reads to the map and avoids many of the Concurrency Exceptions that often result from threaded code sharing a map (not exactly what you describe).

As commenter indicated, even if you invert things (e.g. add/remove or remove/add), you will likely get concurrency exceptions.

Comment: I think this is a single thread environment.. In which case this won't help.. The exception is thrown if your using an iterator and modify the collection outside the iterator - that would occur with the thread safe simple implementation too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises because you are iterating the key set of the map, and modifying the map in the loop. The map doesn't track the fact that you are putting it back in the same state. Any structural modification to the map invalidates existing iterators.

Instead, iterate a copy of the key set, e.g. putting the elements into a `List` to ensure the keys are iterated in the same order vs using the key set directly:

```
for (ValidatorCoordinate v : new ArrayList<>(keys)) {
  // ...
}
```

This is an entirely separate collection from the key set, so modifications to the map have no effect on the iterator.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Can't help but feel like this maaaay be a workaround that avoids some safety measures, but based on my current functionality it won't cause issues so I'll leave it for now and refactor it out, due date permitting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer is to tweak the implementation of tryBlock(..) such that you only move if you are not blocked [rather than trying to undo the move if you are blocked]

```
private boolean tryBlock(ValidatorCoordinate source, 
ValidatorCoordinate destination,
ValidatorCoordinate underAttack, XiangqiColor c){

    boolean blocked = !underAttack(underAttack, c);
    if (!blocked) 
        board.movePiece(source, destination, c);

    return blocked;
```

}

Comment: Ah yes. Sorry I should have clarified context a bit more. Unfortunately the idea is that I'm checking for checkmate in a game. Basically, if a piece *could* move to block the check, then I do not mark the game as over. In order to test this, I move the piece and check if the King is still under attack. Doing it this way protects against things like moving a piece to block the King, only to reveal another attacking piece. Thanks for the feedback though!